# Using react, axios and django, i'm trying to send data from my client side to my server but I can't get the data

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, axios

I'm trying to receive POST data from my client side and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: registrar_usuario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usuario'
```

Here is my code from the client side:

```
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Enviando...");
    const nuevoUsuario = {
        nombre: datosUsuario.nombre,
        apellido: datosUsuario.apellido,
        correo: datosUsuario.email,
        contrasenia: datosUsuario.password
    }
    //const resultado = ApiUtils.registrarUsuario(nuevoUsuario);
    const resultado = axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/registrar_usuario/', nuevoUsuario);
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

And here is the server side:

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
def registrar_usuario(request, usuario):
    print(usuario)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I need help, it's my first time using react, axios, and django so any advice would be helpful

Comment: How about your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `JSON.stringify(nuevoUsuario)`.

Also it would be better if you add them headers

```js
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Enviando...");
    const nuevoUsuario = {
        nombre: datosUsuario.nombre,
        apellido: datosUsuario.apellido,
        correo: datosUsuario.email,
        contrasenia: datosUsuario.password
    }
    return axios.request({
       method:”POST”,
       headers:{
          “Content-Type”: “Application/json”
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(nuevoUsuario)
      }).then(console.log);
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was  i was expecting a parameter "usuario" but i guess it never came because it's a post method. Thanks to your example, i realized the data was in the field "data" of the request so in django i just print what request.data had and that was it.